Selenium IDE Store Attribute xpath The expression is not a legal expression
Selenium IDE returns an error: 'The expression is not a legal expression' even if when the xpath expression in the console returns me the value I am trying to retrieve.
$x('(//div[starts-with(@class, 'commentItem')]/@id)[1]')
Array [ id="C19" ]
Selenium IDE:
| Command          | Target                                                      | Value
| --------         | --------                                                    |
| store attribute  | xpath=(//div[starts-with(@class, \'commentItem\')]/@id)[1]  |Id
| echo             | ${Id}  

                                                 |

Expecting: C19
Actual result:
storeAttribute on xpath=(//div[starts-with(@class, \'commentItem\')]/@id)[1] with value Id Failed:
Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression (//div[starts-with(@class, \'commentItem\')]/ because of the following error: SyntaxError: Document.evaluate: The expression is not a legal expression

